# How can I avoid permission denied errors from php's error_log function when multiple processes are calling it and destination is a custom log file?

Tags: php, cdash

The open source project [CDash](http://www.cdash.org) uses PHP's [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to log info, warnings and errors specific to CDash to a custom log file. By default, this custom log file is in the CDash source tree in "backup/cdash.log"

The file [log.php](https://www.kitware.com/svn/CDash/trunk/cdash/log.php) calls error_log like this:

```
$logged = error_log($error, 3, $logFile);
```

The problem I am observing (on Windows XP with XAMPP 1.8.1 including php 5.4.7) is that when the CDash test suite runs, and multiple processes are trying to write through the CDash `add_log` function, second and later processes get "permission denied" errors until the first process has gone away and released its apparently locking hold on `$logFile`.

How can I avoid permission denied errors from php's error_log function when multiple processes are calling it and destination is a custom log file?

Comment: If I look at that file, it seems it logs to the file that doesn't exist yet, and then changes the file permissions afterwards. Is it only when it rotates (in which case I'd prefer to set a proper `umask(0002)` beforehand), or does it not matter that it rotates (you could set `$CDASH_LOG_FILE_MAXSIZE_MB` to a huge value to see if that matters).

Comment: Yes, but normally error_log creates the file just fine... And this note in the docs seems to indicate you should *not* try to create the file yourself beforehand: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php#95031

Comment: Normally = not during a test run where you're vulnerable for race conditions. Also, that commment is 4 years old, if it is indeed a bug as he says it probably has been fixed. However: let's first determine if it _is_ the problem: if you disable rotating all together for a moment (set the max size to several GB's), does the error still occur?

Comment: The error still occurs with "$CDASH_LOG_FILE_MAXSIZE_MB = 20000;" in my config. Rotating is not involved. If I run the single test "processsubmissions" it runs a php script via php.exe, which spawns a child php.exe with another script as part of its run using a "system()" call. The parent php.exe writes to cdash.log just fine (about 2k characters). The child php.exe consistently gets permission denied errors, even though the parent is *not* writing simultaneously. Furthermore, the subsequent fallback call to error_log for the php system log is also not logging anything to my php_error_log ...

Comment: Hm, OK, so no race condition there... Does the [win32 test in this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40897) also show the errors?

Comment: No, the win32 test shown in that bug report works fine, and I get both processes taking turns logging to test.log

Comment: Damn. And you're sure your're not doing something else with the files, somewhere?